# How to calculate the percentage between two DateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm wondering how to compute the percentage between two DateTimes, I have a BackgroundWorker that executes until a provided DateTime is reached, that part is working fine, I just want to display in the UI what's the percentage completed of the worker.

I tried to use the following approach:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var executeUntil = DateTime.Now..AddHours(4).AddMinutes(10);

var percentage = (int)(( executeUntil.Ticks * 100 ) / now.Ticks );
```

but is always returning 1, i'm guessing that this is because Ticks is a long number and somehow is truncating the division.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var end = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
var total = (end - start).TotalSeconds;

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
Thread.Sleep(6000);

var percentage = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds*100/total;
Console.WriteLine(percentage);
}
```

Comment: You didn't even explain what he was doing wrong...the point of these Q&A sites is to educate people so they won't end up back here.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct about the truncation.  Right now you're dividing by longs so the quotient is going to have `Math.Floor` applied to it and also be a long that doesn't support decimals.  To fix the exact code you gave you need to make either the divisor or the dividend a floating point number.  This quickly makes the numerator a double.

```
var percentage = (int)(( executeUntil.Ticks * 100d ) / now.Ticks );
```